# Upload script works with jQuery v1.3.2, but not with 1.6.2

Tags: jquery, version, compatibility

I would like to use this script to multiple file upload with jQuery v1.6.2. It works well with any version =< 1.3.2, but not with 1.4.x or newer.

Can you please help me to to make it work with 1.6.2?

when I select 3 files to upload, then I remove the first one; all input fields of the 2nd and the 3rd file got removed too. :(

(With jQuery v1.3.2 the the 2nd and the 3rd do not get removed.)

**HTML:**

```
<input type="file" class="upload" name="fileX[]" />
<div id="queue" class="queue"></div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("input.upload").change(function () {
        validateFile(this);
    });


    function validateFile(myelement) {

        //$(myelement).hide();//disabled to test

        $(myelement).parent().prepend('<input type="file" class="upload" name="fileX[]" />').find("input").change(function () {
            validateFile(this)
        });
        var elementval = myelement.value;
        if (elementval != '') {
            $("#queue").append('<div>' + elementval + '&nbsp;&nbsp;<a class="remove">X</a></div>').find("a").live('click', function () {
                $(this).parent().remove();
                $(myelement).remove();
                return true;
            });
        }
    };

});
```

Comment: Try replace `.live()` with `.bind()`?

Comment: jQuery does not take maintaining backwards compatibility between releases seriously.  Your options are basically port the code to the latest version, or continue using the older version.

Comment: i have tried .live() and .blind() but it still does not work. i would like to port it to the last version (1.6.2) because i have another scripts that do not work with 1.3.2

Comment: Can you give us the error message from the browser console?  It could have something to do with `.value` versus `.val()`.

Comment: i tried var elementval = $(myelement).val(); and var elementval = myelement.val(); but i still got the same result. in the browser console, no error message.

Comment: try it at http://jsfiddle.net/NkS5R/ . I am not sure which parts does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still can't figure out why it's removing all the inputs. I can only imagine it has to do with the `myelement` variable being bound to the live click event.  We reuse this variable each time the input change function is called, and I'm not sure how jQuery handles this with those `<a>` click events.  I think I'll do some digging.

I came up with a workaround, though.

Instead of storing the element inside of the live event bound to the `<a>`, I gave the input and the queue div `data-id`'s. So when `#queue a` gets clicked, it matches an input with its own data-id:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var count = 0;
    $('input.upload').live('change', function() {
        $(this).parent().prepend('<input type="file" class="upload" name="fileX[]" />');
        $(this).attr('data-id', count);
        $('#queue').append('<div data-id="' + count + '">' + $(this).val() + '&nbsp;&nbsp;<a class="remove">X</a></div>');
        count++;
    });
    $('#queue div a').live('click', function() {
        $('input[data-id="' + $(this).parent().attr('data-id') + '"]').remove()
        $(this).parent().remove();
    });
});
```

Comment: You safe my day, your workaround is working. Thank you very much!